# Expresso Store: Insert a final confirmation screen AFTER payment interface

Tags: expresso-store, checkout

Our client has requested that we add a final confirmation screen in checkout process that appears after the payment screen. This would seem a pretty simple addition, but having tried unsuccessfully to add one I found this in the Expresso Store docs.

'To give the user a choice between payment methods, you can either use the payment_method="" parameter, or **submit a payment_method field on the last page of your checkout**.'

Which suggests that payment HAS to occur on the last page of checkout wether or not the 'next' parameter is set on the store tag.

Has anyone managed to get a final screen working? If its not possible it would certainly be a useful option in future versions.

Cheers!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting a final confirmation page before payment is submitted to the payment gateway, right?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, yes that is what the client was looking for, but I hadn't really considered that the card details would need to be stored. Looks like this is a bit of a no-no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store doesn't support adding a final confirmation page AFTER you have already taken payment. As soon as payment is successful, the order is complete (that is why payment must be on the last page of your checkout).

You won't be able to support this without significantly modifying the checkout codde, and besides, only a few gateways would support it (the payment gateway would need to support authorize/capture, otherwise we would need to store the credit card details in the database which is a big no-no).

Instead of this, normally you use the final page of the checkout as a "confirmation", where you display the order details, and add a credit card form/paypal button which indicates the customer wants to proceed with the order.

Comment: I hadn't really considered that the card details would need to be stored while the new confirmation screen was shown. This gives me the ammo to push back on the request. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you really need a final confirmation screen AFTER payment because this is what the order confirmation page is for once you're returned to the site after paying for your goods.

I provide an order summary page after the user has entered in the order details and before they make the payment as that is the time you want to display it to give them a final chance to review the order items, totals, shipping, and details before making the payment. I do this by just making an extra page and using the [Next](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#next) attribute along with regular Store tags to sum it all up. The button on that page is the Submit button to make the payment.

Is this what you're after? I just can't see any reason why you'd need one after this page and before the order confirmation page after payment. Both of those cover all bases. If you're having trouble with the code to put that together then feel free to submit that here and I can edit it to show you how I handle it.